# chart Rest Api data not Updating in real time,

Tags: android, graph, anychart

First time Loading data correctly, but second time graph doesn't updating the data.
It is showing the previous graph data again and again.

```
 public class OpdIpdAnalysis extends AppCompatActivity implements NetworkReceiver.ConnectionChangeCallback {

 AnyChartView anyChartView;
 Set set1;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_opd_ipd_analysis);

        anyChartView = findViewById(R.id.anyChartLineChart);
        anyChartView.setProgressBar(myProgressBar);

    }

    private void anyChartGraphViewData(Response<OpdIpdModel.ModelResponse> response) {

        Cartesian cartesian = AnyChart.line();
        cartesian.animation(true);
        cartesian.padding(5d, 10d, 1d, 5d);

        cartesian.crosshair().enabled(true);
        cartesian.crosshair()
                .yLabel(true)
                // TODO ystroke
                .yStroke((Stroke) null, null, null, (String) null, (String) null);

        cartesian.tooltip().positionMode(TooltipPositionMode.POINT);
        cartesian.title("MIS Report of comparing OPD and IPD data.");

        //cartesian.yAxis(0).title("Number of Patient admitted in");
        cartesian.xAxis(0).labels().padding(1d, 1d, 1d, 1d);
        cartesian.xAxis(0).labels().fontSize(8);

        /* Customization Done  */

        List<DataEntry> entries1 = new ArrayList<>();
        //List<DataEntry> entries2 = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<String> xLabel = new ArrayList<>();


        if (response.body() != null) {
            for (OpdIpdModel opdIpdModel : response.body().getOpdIpdComparison()) {

                xLabel.add(opdIpdModel.getYear().shortValue() + "-" + opdIpdModel.getMonthString());

                entries1.add(new CustomDataEntry(xLabel, opdIpdModel.getoPD(), opdIpdModel.getiPD()));
                //entries2.add(new CustomDataEntry(xLabel, opdIpdModel.getoPD(), opdIpdModel.getiPD()));
            }
        }

        set1 = Set.instantiate();
        set1.data(entries1);
        Mapping series1Mapping = set1.mapAs("{ x: 'x', value: 'value1' }");

        //set2 = Set.instantiate();
        //set2.data(entries2);
        Mapping series2Mapping = set1.mapAs("{ x: 'x', value: 'value2' }");


        Line series1 = cartesian.line(series1Mapping);
        series1.name("OPD");
        series1.hovered().markers().enabled(true);
        series1.hovered().markers()
                .type(MarkerType.CIRCLE)
                .size(5d);
        series1.tooltip()
                .position("right")
                .anchor(Anchor.LEFT_CENTER)
                .offsetX(0d)
                .offsetY(0d);

        Line series2 = cartesian.line(series2Mapping);
        series2.name("IPD");
        series2.hovered().markers().enabled(true);
        series2.hovered().markers()
                .type(MarkerType.CIRCLE)
                .size(5d);
        series2.tooltip()
                .position("right")
                .anchor(Anchor.LEFT_CENTER)
                .offsetX(0d)
                .offsetY(0d);

        cartesian.legend().enabled(true);
        cartesian.legend().fontSize(10d);
        cartesian.legend().padding(0d, 0d, 10d, 0d);
        cartesian.interactivity().hoverMode(HoverMode.BY_X);
        //cartesian.xZoom(3);
        cartesian.xScroller(true);
        //cartesian.notifyDataChanged();

        anyChartView.setZoomEnabled(true);
        anyChartView.setChart(cartesian);
        anyChartView.refreshDrawableState();
        anyChartView.invalidate();
        //anyChartView.notify();
    }

private class CustomDataEntry extends ValueDataEntry {

        CustomDataEntry(List<String> x, Number value, Number value2) {
            super(String.valueOf(x), value);
            setValue("value1", value);
            setValue("value2", value2);
        }

    }

    private void allOpdIpdData(String department_id) {

        call = service.getAllOpdIpdData("/Report/GetOpdIpdComparison?departmentId=" + department_id);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<OpdIpdModel.ModelResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<OpdIpdModel.ModelResponse> call, @NotNull Response<OpdIpdModel.ModelResponse> response) {
                myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {

                    updateUI(response.body().getOpdIpdComparison());
                    //graphData(response);
                    /*if (anyChartView != null && anyChartView.isEnabled()){
                        anyChartView.clear();
                    }*/
                    anyChartGraphViewData(response);

                } else {

                    if (response.code() == 401) {

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<OpdIpdModel.ModelResponse> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }

    }
```

I'm using trial version, how to reload Line Chart with new data?

Any Idea, Why it's happening and how to solve this issue?

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to recreate the chart to update the data. All you need is to apply new data to the existing chart. The same issue was raised previously and the solution was provided in my comments below. Please, check [that thread](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android/issues/97#issuecomment-498983079), this should help you.

Comment: I'm pretty new here, Can you Please show me some code, I don't get it, Where i did wrong!